# Why cannot use cout with user-defined conversion to std::string?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, cout

Here I define a `Date`, and specify a user-defined conversion.

```
class Date {
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    string dateStr;
public:
    Date(int _day, int _month) : day(_day), month(_month) {}

    operator const string() {
        ostringstream formattedDate;
        formattedDate << month << "/" << day;
        dateStr = formattedDate.str();
        return dateStr;
    }
};
```

It works well when converting to `string`.

```
Date d(1, 1);
string s = d;
```

But why cannot use it with `cout` directly?

```
cout << d << endl; // The compiler complains that there is no suitable type marching << operator
```

However, if I use `char*` instead of `string` for user-defined conversion, I can use it with `cout` directly. Why?

```
operator const char*() { 
    ostringstream formattedDate;
    formattedDate << month << " / " << day;
    dateStr = formattedDate.str();
    return dateStr.c_str();
}
```

ps. I know that overloading `<<` directly will work well for output. But my question is: **why cannot use `<<` with user-defined conversion to `std::string`?**

Comment: *What* "error" do you get? Build errors? Crashes? Unexpected output? Please copy-paste (as text) it if possible.

Comment: Also, if you want output of your objects, I rather recommend you overload the global `operator<<` function instead of relying on conversion operators. (And if you still want to have a conversion operator, you can use the overloaded `<<` operator to create it.)

Answer (score 14):

Note that `std::string` is an instantiation from template `std::basic_string`, [the signature of `operator<<` for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is indeed:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, 
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

then for `cout << d;`, the template parameter of `std::basic_string` has to be deduced; but [type deduction does not consider implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions);

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

That means the deduction would fail; then no candidate function is viable.

But [`operator<<` for `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) hasn't such kind of problem; implicit conversion takes effect and then works fine.

To solve the issue, you can use explicit conversion to avoid template argument deduction; or overload `operator<<` on the type `Date` directly.

Comment: good answer, maybe add that an explicit conversion should still get the desired result `cout << (std::string)d << endl;` I think

Comment: @xander Please don't suggest using C-style casts in C++. They're the *most dangerous* of all the possible ways to do a type conversion.

Comment: @Angew but that is not a classic cast, it's an explicit type conversion calling the `operator string()`. I'm not sure how to call it with C++ cast style, can you use a `static_cast<std::string>(d)` for this or what would be the proper way?

Comment: @xander Yes, you'd use `static_cast`, or you could also use `std::string{d}`. `(Type)expr` is always a C-style cast and can do any of the following: static, static+const, reinterpret, reinterpret+const; depending on `Type` and `expr`. That's why it's such a bad idea to use it: you don't really know what will happen.