# Implicit Conversion Operator for Class Objects to Strings

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

I'm learning more about implicit conversion operators, and I've noticed something strange with implicit user-defined conversions for strings. Found below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

class A {
    public:
        A() {
            *value = "YIKERS";
        } 
        operator string&() {
            return *this->value;
        }
        string* value;
};


int main() {
    A abc;
    cout << abc << endl; 
// compile error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka
// 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'A')
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this compilation error? I'm thinking this could mean that the object isn't being implicitly converted to a string? If so, why not? Is there a way to fix this? The conversion operator works perfectly fine for other data types like int, float, char, etc.

Comment: ot: you should store a `std::string` instead of a pointer to string. It is not relevant for your question, but it would make your code a little less "surprising"

Comment: Even if the code compiled, it still wouldn't work properly, because the `A` constructor is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, causing *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why is it an invalid pointer?

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is just a mini-part of my overall implementation. My code requires that the member variable is a pointer.

Comment: "My code requires that the member variable is a pointer" i strongly doubt that it needs to be a raw pointer.

Comment: @MAGEPAC "*Why is it an invalid pointer?*" - because you are not assigning a valid memory address to the pointer, before dereferencing it to assign data to memory at that address. Given what you are attempting, you need to allocate a valid `string` object and assign its memory address to the pointer. Use `new` for that. And then make sure `A` follows the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to ensure that `string` object is managed properly.

Comment: the question would be better if you show the same code with the `int` conversion and the working  `<<`. It also would be better if you don't use a raw pointer as member. Tough, you already got an answer, which makes it difficult to change the question...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Apologies. I forgot to add ```new```, in my code I actually dynamically allocate it upon construction and handle potential memory leaks, etc. I need to get some more coffee! But other than that, I still do not understand why the ```operator<<``` is not overloaded for strings using the given implicit user-defined conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think you're not using `std::string value` as intended. This causes another compile error (at least on gcc 10.2).
It seems like you want a string and you're using a pointer to a string.
This can be fixed by replace `string* value` with `string value`, `operator string&()` with `operator string()` and `*value = "YIKERS'` with `value = "YIKERS"`. For the last one you might also want to check initializer lists.

Regarding the current compile error:

The compile error is caused by the code `cout << abc` trying to use operator<< on an `abc` which is an object of type `A`. However, you did not overload this operator.
In your example this could be something like

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, const A &a ) 
{ 
    output << a.value;
    return output;            
}
```

Even if you have a user-defined conversion to `std::string` you would still get compile time errors. This link explains it better than I think I could [Why cannot use cout with user-defined conversion to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994851/why-cannot-use-cout-with-user-defined-conversion-to-stdstring)

This is how I understand the explanation from link above:

`string` header defines the following overload for `operator<<` for `std::basic_ostream`:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Also, `std::string` is actually a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`.

However, if the conversion is implicit the following rule kicks in:

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type
> adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution,
> which happens later.

So, the compiler cannot deduce the second parameter for the function (e.g. `const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str`) from `A`. It can, however, deduce it for `string` so you can explicitly convert `abc` to `string` like `static_cast<string>(abc)` and that would work.

Comment: I see. It looks like I will have to change my design. The operator<< should be automatically overloaded if we implicitly define a conversion operator. Also, if we changed the conversion operator from ```operator string&()``` to  ```operator string()``` then it will not support operators that should return lvalues, like the hybrid assignment operators ```*=```, ```++```, etc.

Comment: @TwoOfDiamonds `operator<<` is overloaded to accept a `const string&` as input. It is clear that the OP intends the `A` object to convert implicitly to `string` so that overload is called. This answer would be more useful if you expand it to explain why that overload is not actually being called as expected.

Comment: @MAGEPAC "*The operator<< should be automatically overloaded if we implicitly define a conversion operator* - no, it shouldn't be automatic. That is not how operator overloading works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Perhaps I may have phrased it incorrectly. I meant that the ```operator<<``` should still work as it supports ```string``` objects, for which this object has an implicit conversion operator.

Comment: So the solution is to declare operator overloads manually as needed?

Comment: In my experience, yes. Or you can explicitly cast `abc` to `std::string` (e.g. `cout << static_cast<string>(abc)`