# Why implicit conversion doesn't work when inserting to map

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have a structure that is implicitly convertable to the type that is acceptable by the `std::map::insert()` function.

I use a structure as-is, but I have compilation error:

> no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

However, if I explicitly convert the structure using `static_cast`, it is accepted.

My question is, why does implicit conversion not work here?

**Example code:**

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(std::string s, int i) : data(s, i) {}
    operator std::pair<std::string, int>() const
    {
        return data;
    }

private:
    std::pair<std::string, int> data;
};

MyStruct my_val1("hello", 4);
MyStruct my_val2("world", 2);

std::map<std::string, int> my_map {};
my_map.insert(static_cast<std::pair<std::string, int>>(my_val1)); // compiles
my_map.insert(my_val2);                                           // not compiles
```

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994851/why-cannot-use-cout-with-user-defined-conversion-to-stdstring

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue is that `value_type` of `my_map` is `std::pair<const std::string, int>`, not `std::pair<std::string, int>` like you have for your conversion operator.

This means that converting `my_val2` requires two user-defined conversions<sup>1</sup> to get to `std::pair<const std::string, int>`, but you are only ever allowed to have up to one user-defined conversion in an implicit conversion sequence.

The `static_cast` works as that is an explicit cast, so there is just the one implicit user-defined conversion to go from `std::pair<std::string, int>` to `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.

---

Changing your operator to `operator std::pair<const std::string, int>() const` will allow `my_map.insert(my_val2);` to compile, as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b735b2f6a4c063f).

---

<sup>1: even standard library types are considered user-defined.  Non user-defined types are things that the core language supports, like `int`.</sup>